# grapheme š is always bold

Tags: css, google-webfonts, grapheme

i'm fighting with the font-style of š since hours.

i'm using the webfont "open sans" from google webfonts and tested the grapheme on googles review option. everything's fine, the š is thin and beautiful like the rest of the font. (sorry i cant post images yet)

but at my site the š is always bold! i reseted all stylesheets to make sure nothing is overwriting the font-weight or something. 
my document is utf-8 and i tried both ways to post the grapheme: š and `&scaron;`

i scanned googles quellcode to find the magic to display the grapheme correctly but couldnt find the solution :(

anybody can help me with this problem?

online example: http://korasu.de/font/

Comment: Would you be able to link some code? Or even better, include your code in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your font doesn't come with a character for `š`, and its style fallbacks to `sans-serif`.

You should expand your character set here (thanks @Jukka K. Korpela for pointing out that Latin and Latin Extended are enough for this case):
[image: character set]
And link to an extended webfont stylesheet:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Then your `š` would come beautifully: [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/aponef/5/).

Comment: Adding `&subset=latin,latin-ext` is sufficient, unless the page actually contains Cyrillic, Greek, or special Vietnamese characters. Adding unneeded subsets increases the amount of data transferred.